# how to have a variable session in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

Sorry for my question, i'm a junior.

When two different user is connect in my node server, my variable cross and the result is wrong.

I read i must use the session for my variable in nodejs, but i don't know how to use.

When i console.log my variable 'Pseudo', sometimes i have the wrong result if two user is connect.

Please help me :(

```
//Le modules
var express = require('express'),
bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
session = require('express-session'),
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
app = express(),
//mongoose = require('mongoose'),
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
//assert = require('assert'),
ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
device = require('express-device'),
morgan = require('morgan'),
fs = require('fs'),
path = require('path'),
log4js = require('log4js'),

//Module complémentaire pour MORGAN
accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname,'access.log'), {
    flags: 'a'
}),

myDate = new Date;


app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(device.capture()); //Module pour connaitre la plate-forme deconnection (PC, tablette, mobile...)
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/fichiers'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended: false
}));
app.use(morgan('combined', {
stream: accessLogStream
}));

app.use(session({
secret: '123456789SECRET',
saveUninitialized: false,
resave: false,
cookie: {
    maxAge: 10000
}
}))

app.set('view engine', 'jade'); // Template HTML
app.set('views', './fichiers'); // Dire à JADE où sont les fichiers.



var pseudo = '';

app.get('/blindtest', function (req,res){
res.render('blindtest');
})

app.post('/envoiPseudo', function (req,res){
return pseudo = req.body.pseudo;
})

app.get('/test', function (req,res){
console.log(pseudo);
})

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
var adressHost = server.address().address;
var portHost = server.address().port;
console.log('Ecoute à l\'adresse http://%s:%s', adressHost, portHost);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting pseudo as a variable inside your app.js, you need to assign it to the users session. You can access (and set) session variables by doing

```
req.session.[variable]
```

A quick example would be:

```
app.post('/envoiPseudo', function (req,res){
req.session.pseudo = 'this is unique to the user requesting';
console.log(req.session.pseudo);
res.send("pseudo session variable: " + req.session.pseudo);
})
```

**Edit:**
As jfriend00 said, you shouldn't be "returning" variables like that. You should be adding things to the response (res) and sending that.

Comment: Please remove the `return pseudo = req.body.pseudo;` from your answer as this is a very bad practice.  The point of the rest of your answer is that that line is not needed and should not be used.